# This site can’t be reached in Chrome after deploying ASP.Net webapplication in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis

This site can’t be reached in Chrome after deploying ASP.Net webapplication in iis 
but its working in internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

You should revert HTTP.sys to its earlier settings. If you are in Windows 7 or Windows Vista, run the following command from an elevated command prompt, depends on what port you used. Hope it helps.

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://localhost:80/
```

If XP:

```
httpcfg delete urlacl /u http://localhost:80/
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing with me.

I didn't find any problem with the urlacls so that wasn't my issue.

After a few hours of troubling shooting rebooting the server fixed it!!!